# React Native Video Player

Tags: react-native, expo, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am trying to use vimeo to build a mobile app that show list of videos , I finished everything from hosting the videos and fetch them using react native , one problem that I have is the embedding the videos using web-view was not enough , as you can see in the screenshot , the video player controls are very small , is there a way to make them bigger.

[image]

here is my code

```
<WebView
              javaScriptEnabled={true}
              allowsFullscreenVideo={true}
              source={{
                html: `<div style='padding:56.25% 0 0 0;position:relative; height: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            max-width: 100%; '>
           <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video${
             currentVideo ? currentVideo : ""
           }" style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;' frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen " allowfullscreen></iframe></div>`,
              }}
            />
```

thank you so much in advance.